# jQplot Bar Colours Are Wrong With Negative Values

Tags: jquery, css, jqplot

See the attached image, the bar colours are wrong when there are values 0 or below. I have the code set like this:

```
seriesColors:['#09c700','#ff0000','#3854ff']

negativeSeriesColors:['#09c700','#ff0000','#3854ff']
```

It seems when a value is 0 or lower it skips the colour. My colour settings are set so the first bar should be *green*, the second *red* and the third *blue*, but you can see it's made the second bar (middle) blue and the last one red and this only happens because the middle bar is a negative value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it's using "negative" colors, which are separate from your defined "positive" colors.  You can disable the negative colors with `useNegativeColors: false` on the series render options.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var line1 = [['Nissan', 4],['Porche', -6],['Acura', 2]];
 
    $('#chart').jqplot([line1], {
        title:'Bar Chart with Custom Colors',
        seriesColors:['#09c700','#ff0000','#3854ff'],
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                varyBarColor: true,
                fillToZero: true,
                useNegativeColors: false
            }
        },
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```